# I am writing test script for mobile number validation, where i have to verify that all characters in mobile field should not be zero.

Tags: selenium

I am writing test script for mobile number validation, where i have to verify that all characters in mobile field should not be zero. Can someone help me solve this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so,

```
String mobileNumber = "1234567890";

if(mobileNumber.matches("(.*?0.*?){5}"))
{
    // Number does not pass validation
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but few mobiles number contains zero value, but i need to verify if number contains more than 5 zero values

Comment: I have written below code  ` driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys(Constants.ZERO_MOBILE);
     if(Constants.ZERO_MOBILE.matches("/0{5,}/")){
      System.out.println("Mobile number should not contains all zero values");
     }
     else{
      System.out.println("Ok, zero number validation failed");
     }
    }`

Comment: @Yogesh I have updated my answer to reflect that 5 zeroes in the phone number is considered invalid. Please edit your question and add this information there as well.